# Sort Function in OCaml not working

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, ocaml

New to OCaml and learning I am. I wrote the function below. Would you say this function is OK? Well I get an error but does the algorithm makes sense? And how can I correct it.

```
let rec sort l =
    match l with 
    [] -> []
    |h::t -> insert h (sort t)
;;

let rec insert x l =
    match l with
    [] -> [x]
    |h::t ->
        if x <= h
            then x :: h :: t
    else h :: insert x t
;;


sort [3; 2; 8; 4; 1];;
```

I get in my terminal: 
`Error: Unbound value sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you give here, it's `insert` that's not defined when you use it.

If I put the definition of `insert` first, it works fine for me. It seems like good code as far as I can tell (though not a particularly fast sort).

I would try starting up your OCaml from scratch again. You probably have some old definitions that are confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. I should have made the order of functions so that `insert` comes before `sort` :)

```
(* Sort a list *)

let rec insert x l =
    match l with
    [] -> [x]
    |h::t ->
        if x <= h
            then x :: h :: t
    else h :: insert x t
;;

let rec sort l =
    match l with 
    [] -> []
    |h::t -> insert h (sort t)
;;




sort [3; 2; 8; 4; 1];;
```

The `sort` function is dependent on the `insert` function and to OCaml, calling the `sort` function makes no sense because the it doesn't know the `insert` function just yet. So changing the order of function definition fixes the problem.